# Django Rest Framework Error 404 detail“: ”Not found."

Tags: python, django

When i go to `localhost:8000/api/create` i get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nvtW.jpg

**views.py**:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from rest_framework.generics import (
    ListAPIView,
     RetrieveAPIView,
     CreateAPIView,
#    DestroyAPIView,
#    UpdateAPIView
)

from articles.models import Article
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer

class ArticleListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer


class ArticleDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer


class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import ArticleListView, ArticleDetailView, ArticleCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view()),
    path('create/', ArticleCreateView.as_view()),
    path('<pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view()),

]
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Article Model
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm on windows 10, using python 3.7.1 i don't know what else to write but i'm writing these words so this thing will let me post, ignore this.

Comment: Try removing the "/" after "create" in your urls

Comment: @MattSalzman it works, wow thank you very much!